# OSError: [Errno 10048] in aiohttp test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I wanted to write some py.tests for my aiohttp web application. I started with a simple test:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(body=b'Hello, world')

def create_app(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', hello)
    return app

async def test_hello(test_client):
    client = await test_client(create_app)
    resp = await client.get('/')
    assert resp.status == 200
    text = await resp.text()
    assert 'Hello, world' in text
```

But when I run it, it fails with the following message:

```
...
# Disable IPv4/IPv6 dual stack support (enabled by
# default on Linux) which makes a single socket
# listen on both address families.
if af == AF_INET6 and hasattr(socket, 'IPPROTO_IPV6'):
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6,
                    socket.IPV6_V6ONLY,
                    True)
try:
    sock.bind(sa)
except OSError as err:
    raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
                  'to bind on address %r: %s'
>   % (sa, err.strerror.lower()))
E   OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 65214): обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)

C:\Python35\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:962: OSError
========================== 1 failed in 0.66 seconds ===========================
```

Here is the content of the aiohttp\test_utils.py:

```
def unused_port():
    """Return a port that is unused on the current host."""
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
        return s.getsockname()[1]


class TestServer:
    def __init__(self, app, *, scheme="http", host='127.0.0.1'):
        self.app = app
        self._loop = app.loop
        self.port = None
        self.server = None
        self.handler = None
        self._root = None
        self.host = host
        self.scheme = scheme
        self._closed = False

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def start_server(self, **kwargs):
        if self.server:
            return
        self.port = unused_port()
        self._root = '{}://{}:{}'.format(self.scheme, self.host, self.port)
        self.handler = self.app.make_handler(**kwargs)
```

I found that if I specify self.port manually, for example, 65214, and then run the test, it'll ends successfully. Maybe someone can explain why this error occurs? I'm using Windows 7 x64, Python 3.5.2 with virtualenv, aiohttp 1.0.5, pytest 3.0.3, pytest-aiohttp 0.1.3.

Comment: Sounds strange because aiohttp uses `test_client` in self test suite -- and run its on Windows on every commit.

Comment: Looks like the problem is on my system, I ran this test on a Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16, but could not reproduce the error. By the way, thank you for creating aiohttp.